# Windows 7 / Windows Vista won't connect to 802.1x RADIUS Server

Tags: windows-7, authentication, windows-vista, radius, 802.1

I've deployed Radius and have no problems connecting with TTLS, PEAP, or MD5 using linux, mac, and windows xp.  For Windows 7 and Vista, I'm never prompted with the dialog box to enter username & password after configuring 802.1x support on the client.

Steps taken:

1. Enabled Wired Autoconfig in services.msc
2. Set to use PEAP
3. Set to require user authentication

When I enable the network connection it says "Trying to authenticate" then fails with no error log / message given.  The radius server gives no indication that there was ever a request (no Access-Reject - the client simply never tries to authenticate).

On the windows 7 client, I can see that the DHCP server does not assign an IP to the client when 802.1x is enabled on the client (though it does when it isn't).

How can I debug this further?  Has anyone else run into a similar situation?

My radius server is freeradius on Ubuntu 11.10.